# Como verificar cada caracter de um array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

Pessoa, eu estou com este código:

```js
const arrayOne = ['jean','geleia','gean','ea games', 'e1'];

function buscar(){
  arrayOne.forEach(function(valor){
     const teste1 = document.getElementById('valorInput').value;       
      if(teste1 === valor){
        alert (true)
      } else {
        alert(false)
      }
  })  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input id='valorInput'/> 
    <button onClick='buscar()'> Buscar </button>
    
    <h1 id='resultado'> Resultado </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Eu queria saber como eu faço para que, quando eu digitasse a letra 'a' ele retornasse `true` nas palavras que existem a letra 'a'?

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Isso parece me um problema XY. Se a ideia é buscar os nomes que correspondem ao que o usuario escreveu o melhor é mesmo utilizar `filter` com `const nomesFiltrados = arrayOne.filter(nome=>nome.indexOf(teste1) !== -1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber se um elemento existe dentro de um array ou palavra, pode usar a função [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) da seguinte forma:

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

Caso o valor da variável index seja negativo, quer dizer que o elemento não existe dentro do(a) array/palavra.

Comment: Boa tarde Paulo, obrigado por responder. Mas se eu quiser saber se existe uma letra dentro de uma determinada palavra do array, eu consigo usando o indexOf?

Comment: Como já está percorrendo cada elemento do array no foreach no if pode colocar `valor.indexOf(teste1) < 0`, onde valor é o elemento do array que está sendo avaliado no momento e o teste1 o que foi digitado.

Comment: Nossa cara, muito obrigado. Funcionou.

Poderia me explica uma coisa?

Quando usamos essa expressão
`valor.indexOf(teste1) < 0`, significa que o index do valor.indexOf vai ser o teste1 ?

Comment: A função retorna um inteiro, valor que é o da posição, aí da pra colocar numa variável, feito esse exemplo que dei em cima do array, aí caso não ache ele retona -1, por isso essa validação do < 0.

Answer (score 1):

A forma correta é usar `indexOf` sobre o valor de cada item da array, representado pelo parâmetro `valor` no `forEach`:

```js
const arrayOne = ['jean','geleia','gean','ea games', 'e1'];

function buscar(){
  arrayOne.forEach(function(valor){
     const teste1 = document.getElementById('valorInput').value;       
      if(valor.indexOf(teste1) !== -1){
        console.log (true)
      } else {
        console.log (false)
      }
  })  
}
```

```html
<input id='valorInput'/> 
<button onClick='buscar()'> Buscar </button>

<h1 id='resultado'> Resultado </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode usar o [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
var s = 'an';
arrayOne.filter(x => x.includes(s)); // ["jean", "gean"]
```